# How do i change the color of all other columns except the one i clicked on? (react-chartjs-2)

Tags: reactjs, react-chartjs-2

I would like all columns except the one I clicked to become transparent by 0.5

How can I do this?

Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/github/reactchartjs/react-chartjs-2/tree/master/sandboxes/chart/events?from-embed

Comment: Do you mean clicking on a DataSet or a point in the Graph?

Comment: @BaptisteRieber, I mean this bar: http://joxi.ru/gmvk0JgHeZWXj2